# Element not appearing on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a basic website header and the respective menus should appear when you hover over the options but it doesn't work. When hovering over the options "Home" "Insert" "design" "table" "info" etc the respective menus should appear. I have made menus and did dispaly:none on them to make them disappear and put display:block on the options to make the menus appear when you hover over them. What is the mistake pls help.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: calibri;
  padding: 8 20 8 20;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
  border-bottom: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
}

#insertmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 23.5%;
  display: none;
}

#viewmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;
  display: none;
}

#tablemenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;
  display: none;
}

#designmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;
  display: none;
}

#li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

#insert:hover+#insertmenu {
  display: block;
}

#view:hover+#viewmenu {
  display: block;
}

#table:hover+#tablemenu {
  display: block;
}

#design:hover+#designmenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> Home </li>
  <li id="insert"> Insert </li>
  <li id="view"> View </li>
  <li id="table"> Table </li>
  <li id="design"> Design </li>
  <li> Info </li>

</ol>

<br> <br> <br>

<ol>
  <li id="insertmenu">
    Photos Videos Table
  </li>

  <li id="viewmenu">
    Chart Pictures Videos
  </li>

  <li id="tablemenu">
    Chart Pictures Videos
  </li>

  <li id="designmenu">
    Chart Pictures Videos
  </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: Try #insert:hover , #insertmenu instead of #insert:hover + #insertmenu

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have your submenu in a different list ? you could merge some element (and a lot of css)

Comment: @Cédric i want the menus insertmenu, viewmenu designmenu, tablemenu etc to only appear when you hover over their respective options that are insert' view, design, table. and if i write a common css style for all these menus, all the menus wil appear together when you hover over the options

Comment: The HTML structure is wrong to begin with, which is pointed out by Cedric. The submenus should be a child to the menus, and not a separate element of it's own.

Comment: @ManuelEspinosa writing #insert:hover , #insertmenu makes all the menus appear automatically for some reason. I only want them to appear when you hover over the options

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp for more information. You can also look for _Resp Navbar with Dropdown_, _Subnavigation menu_ and _Mega menu_ in the links to the left.

Comment: Instead of creating whole menu css/js by hand, why dont you use bootstrap framework? you will get all required css and js readymade.

Comment: @Sudhir loading a whole framework for a single use is not a good practice.

Comment: @Cédric I do agree with you. But I was not sure if its single use. From the question it appeared to have multiple pages and sounded like reinventing the wheel. Nevertheless, if its single use, you are right.

Comment: @Sudhir i am just learning how to code and was trying to figure out how to make a working menu for a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

In your case with your HTML structure you cant archive this with pur CSS. You have to use Javascript. Take a look of this small working example. I refactor your code only a little bit. But you will see how it works and you can adjusting for your wishes.

```js
function showBox(sel) {  
  const el = document.getElementById(sel);
  el.classList.remove('hide');  
}

function hideBox(sel) {
  const el = document.getElementById(sel);
  el.classList.add('hide');    
}
```

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9%;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: calibri;
  padding: 8 20 8 20;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
  border-bottom: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
}

#insertmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 23.5%;  
}

#viewmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%; 
}

#tablemenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;  
}

#designmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;  
}

ol li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> Home </li>
  <li id="insert" onmouseover="showBox('insertmenu')" onmouseout="hideBox('insertmenu')"> Insert </li>
  <li id="view" onmouseover="showBox('viewmenu')" onmouseout="hideBox('viewmenu')"> View </li>
  <li id="table" onmouseover="showBox('tablemenu')" onmouseout="hideBox('tablemenu')"> Table </li>
  <li id="design" onmouseover="showBox('designmenu')" onmouseout="hideBox('designmenu')"> Design </li>
  <li> Info </li>

</ol>

<br> <br> <br>

<ol>
  <li id="insertmenu" class="hide">
    Photos Videos Table
  </li>

  <li id="viewmenu" class="hide">
    Chart Pictures Videos
  </li>

  <li id="tablemenu" class="hide">
    Chart Pictures Videos
  </li>

  <li id="designmenu" class="hide">
    Chart Pictures Videos
  </li>

</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible with CSS only but you have a "setup/layout" that won't allow it due to the nesting your are using.

There is no CSS selector that allows you to move OUT of the `<ol>` elements and find the other `<li>` elements INSIDE the seconds `<ol>`.

Additionally the `+` operator in CSS won't work here either as it only looks for directly adjacent elements (if I'm not mistaken! Please verify for yourself!).

The Operator you are looking for is the "tilde" operator `~`.

I've provided a working example that might explain better what I mean:

```css
.fake-li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: calibri;
  padding: 8 20 8 20;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-top: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
  border-bottom: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
}

#insertmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 23.5%;
  display: none;
}

#viewmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;
  display: none;
}

#tablemenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;
  display: none;
}

#designmenu {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20 10 20 10;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-left: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  border-right: 4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 7%;
  display: none;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

#insert:hover ~ #insertmenu {
  display: block;
}

#view:hover ~ #viewmenu {
  display: block;
}

#table:hover ~ #tablemenu {
  display: block;
}

#design:hover ~ #designmenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fake-li">Home</div>
<div id="insert" class="fake-li">Insert</div>
<div id="view" class="fake-li">View</div>
<div id="table" class="fake-li">Table</div>
<div id="design" class="fake-li">Design</div>
<div class="fake-li">Info</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<div id="insertmenu" class="fake-li">Photos Videos Table</div>
<div id="viewmenu" class="fake-li">Chart Pictures Videos</div>
<div id="tablemenu" class="fake-li">Chart Pictures Videos</div>
<div id="designmenu" class="fake-li">Chart Pictures Videos</div>
```

Comment: Horrible makeup, please don't use this as a starting point. Rather have a look at semantic markup and don't use just divs here.

Comment: @flx  Good answer. If the Question Owner change his HTML Structure it would be possible with pur CSS. But in his case with his HTML structure it is not possible with CSS. Then he have to use Javascript. As i have already pointed out in my answer. i give you +1up because the css solution with changed dom would be a good solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I got to work with just CSS. I just changed the ol/ul part. Instead of having a separate ol for the menus, I put the menus inside the main headings of the ol as a ul and it works now.

```css
ol {
list-style: none;
}


li {
float:left;
margin-left:7.5%;
font-size:25px;
font-family: calibri;
padding:8 20 8 20;
background-color:skyblue;
border-radius: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
border-top: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
border-bottom: 5px rgb(53, 53, 185) groove;
position:relative;
}

#insertmenu {
font-size: 25px;
background-color: skyblue;
width:100px;
padding:20 10 20 10;
font-family:calibri;
border-radius: 10px;
border-left:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
border-right:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:-60px;
display: none;
position:absolute;
}

#viewmenu {
font-size: 25px;
background-color: skyblue;
width:100px;
padding:20 10 20 10;
font-family:calibri;
border-radius: 10px;
border-left:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
border-right:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:-60px;
display: none;
position:absolute;
}

#tablemenu {
font-size: 25px;
background-color: skyblue;
width:100px;
padding:20 10 20 10;
font-family:calibri;
border-radius: 10px;
border-left:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
border-right:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:-60px;
display: none;
position:absolute;
}

#designmenu {
font-size: 25px;
background-color: skyblue;
width:100px;
padding:20 10 20 10;
font-family:calibri;
border-radius: 10px;
border-left:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
border-right:4px rgb(20, 20, 119) solid;
margin-top:40px;
margin-left:-60px;
display: none;
position:absolute;
}

li:hover{
    background-color: white;
}

#insert:hover #insertmenu {
    display:block;
}

#view:hover #viewmenu {
    display:block;
}

#table:hover #tablemenu {
    display:block;
}

#design:hover #designmenu {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li> Home </li>
   
    <li id="insert"> Insert
     <ol> 
         <li id="insertmenu"> 
             Photos 
             Videos
             Table

         </li>
        
    </ol> </li>
    
    <li id="view"> View 
    <ol> 
        <li id="viewmenu"> 
            Photos 
            Videos
            Table

        </li>
       
   </ol></li>
    
   <li id="table"> Table
    <ol> 
        <li id="tablemenu"> 
            Photos 
            Videos
            Table

        </li>
       
   </ol> </li>
   
   <li id="design"> Design 
    <ol> 
        <li id="designmenu"> 
            Photos 
            Videos
            Table

        </li>
       
   </ol> </li>
   
   <li> Info </li>
    
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your decision and feedback. Both way (1. CSS only,, 2. JS solution) are good and you are free to choice. If your HTML grows maybe you have to switch. One small note to your current code above. It looks not complete.

Comment: @MaikLowrey I am still learning to code and dont know a lot. Also these dropdown menus move all the other elements whenever they appear. So if i have a image on the website below the menu, the entire image will move down to make space for the dropdown menu Is there a good way to make dropdown menus that appear over all the other elements.

Comment: That is true. It would be one solution to avoid the sliding effect. Work with position relative, absolute to archive this.